# Fortran Make file for windows

Tags: windows, command-line, makefile, fortran, fortran90

Please could you help me how to convert FORTRAN make file for Linux to a make file for FORTRAN under windows?

my Linux make file here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ui6pbtwmumc5zpz/makefile.txt

Also I don't know what is the command the I have to write in the command window, while in Linux I run it like

make clean and make commands

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

Answer (score -1):

On Windows a while back, I used the command "nmake".  Don't know if it will work for you, but that's what I would try.  I probably can't help much with the make file.

Answer (score -1):

You could always use scons.  Just install python on your windows box, download the scons scripts, create the SConscript file as in the tutorial and run.  Try it on Linux first then just transfer your SConscript file to windows and run it.  It will build on most platforms.

[scons](http://www.scons.org/)